# How to find the $L^{\infty}$-space?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Suppose we have a non-empty set $Y$ and $\mu$ is a measure defined by $\mu(\varnothing)=0$ and $\mu(A)=+\infty$ for all non-empty set $A$ of $Y$. I would like to determine the space $L^{\infty}(Y,\mu)$.

**My answer**: Since $\mu(\varnothing)=0$, it follows that every bounded function is in the space $L^{\infty}(Y,\mu)$. If there is $f\in L^{\infty}(Y,\mu)$ where $f$ is unbounded on $Y$, then we can find $M>0$ such that $|f(y)|\leq M$ for almost all $y\in Y$. This means that the set 
$$A=\{y\in Y:|f(y)|>M\}\neq \varnothing$$
and so, $\mu(A)=0$, contradicting the assumption. Thus, $L^{\infty}(Y,\mu)$
contains exactly all the bounded functions defined on $Y$.

**Question**: Is my answer correct?

Comment: No, hold on a moment, I made a mistake.

Comment: @ copper.hat  Okay, I will wait.  Thanks

Comment: My apologies, the question is a little different that the one you linked. You are correct, the space consists of the bounded functions. However, I find it a little hard to follow your logic above.

Comment: I'm deleting my embarrassing comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $f \in L^\infty(Y,\mu)$. Then
$\|f\|_\infty = \text{ess sup} |f| < \infty$.
Hence if $\alpha > \|f\|_\infty$, we have
$\mu\{ x | |f(x)| > \alpha\} = 0$ and hence $\{ x | |f(x)| > \alpha\} =  \emptyset $ and hence $|f(x)| \le \alpha $ for all $x$ and so $f$ is bounded.

Now suppose $f$ is bounded, then $|f(x)| \le M$ for some $M\ge 0$. In particular, if $\alpha >M$ we have
$\{ x | |f(x)| > \alpha\} =  \emptyset $ and so $\mu\{ x | |f(x)| > \alpha\} = 0$ and $\|f\|_\infty \le \alpha$ and so $f \in L^\infty(Y,\mu)$.